# How can I check whether server received all of my request HTTP headers

Tags: curl, connection, traceroute

For some of the requests I'm making from my server to an external service I receive error which in general means that server didn't receive content type header and is unable to process my request.

My assumption is that the header is lost somewhere between my machine and target (maybe some router cut it off). Is it possible to configure `curl`, `mtr` or `traceroute` so it can show me not only the hops it reached during the communication but the state of headers at specific hop?

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for your question
The first: I'm using `mod_log_forensic` with `Apache`
The second: How to enable `mod_log_forensic`:

```
sudo a2enmod log_forensic
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The third: Add following line in `apache2.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
Add: ForensicLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/forensic_log.log
Ctrl W -> y -> Enter
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And this is my tested result:

```
+6274:578ccd9a:0|GET /testGuzzle/poslaju.php HTTP/1.1|Host:localhost|User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv%3a47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0|Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8|Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5|Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate|Cookie:private_content_version=373c9750d1047a67b04e6e071b4af4f4; AMCV_8412403D53AC3D7E0A490D4C%2540AdobeOrg=-1248264605%257CMCIDTS%257C16998%257CMCMID%257C84157576296970390370374071592259585472%257CMCAAMLH-1469208963%257C3%257CMCAAMB-1469208963%257CNRX38WO0n5BH8Th-nqAG_A%257CMCOPTOUT-1468611364s%257CNONE%257CMCAID%257CNONE; _qst_s=2; __gads=ID=d32ab535bdb59060%3aT=1468604164%3aS=ALNI_MZVO9HokfpeaFCE4zulMCb6OK-bCQ; _ga=GA1.1.1975741070.1468684196|Connection:keep-alive-6274:578ccd9a:0
```

Comment: hi, thanks for response, however I don't have Apache installed on my server (Nginx instead)